# How can I implement loginHandler for HashDB in Yesod?

Tags: authentication, haskell, yesod

I'm implementing username/password based authentication in Yesod using Yesod.Auth.HashDB and I'd like to apply some styling to the login page. I think I can do this using the `loginHandler` function of the [YesodAuth typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.1.1/docs/Yesod-Auth.html), but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to handle this before posting my question:

```
loginHandler = do
    lift $ defaultLayout $(widgetFile "auth")
```

where `auth` is a widget composed of at least an `auth.hamlet` file inside your templates.

Answer (score 1):

As of yesod-auth-hashdb 1.3.2, you can now also use authHashDBWithForm. I was unable to figure out how to get POST to work with loginHandler and a custom widget file (no examples anywhere). Then I followed the example for authHashDBWithForm and it worked very well.

From the [docs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paul-rouse/yesod-auth-hashdb/master/Yesod/Auth/HashDB.hs)

> == Custom Login Form
>
> Instead of using the built-in HTML form, a custom one can be supplied
> by using 'authHashDBWithForm' instead of 'authHashDB'.
>
> The custom form needs to be given as a function returning a Widget, since
> it has to build in the supplied "action" URL, and it must provide two text
> fields called "username" and "password".  For example, the following
> modification of the outline code given above would replace the default
> form with a very minimal one which has no labels and a simple layout.

```
instance YesodAuth App where
   ....
   authPlugins _ = [ authHashDBWithForm myform (Just . UniqueUser), .... ]

myform :: Route App -> Widget
myform action = $(whamletFile "templates/loginform.hamlet")
```

> where templates/loginform.hamlet contains

```
<form method="post" action="@{action}">
    <input name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
```